# Trouble launching activity from class method

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and Android Studio, and to learn I'm building a character generator app for Dungeons and Dragons. You choose a race, character class, and skills, then the app calculates everything and builds a final character sheet.

I have an activity that allows the user to select a class (fighter, wizard, etc.) from a list. It then stores the selection in a SharedPreferences File.

I want to call different sub activities for different classes. In these activities, a selection is made and is written to the SharedPreferences File. For example, a fighter gets to choose a fighting style while a wizard gets to choose spells.

Right now I have a (java)class for the fighter class, and one for the wizard class. Both have a public void create() method.

Calling the method:

```
if (chosenClass.equalsIgnoreCase("fighter")){
            Fighter classObject = new Fighter();
            Fighter.create();
        }
```

Here is the code from the Fighter class:

```
import android.content.Intent;

public class Fighter {

    public Fighter(){}

    public void create(){
        Intent fightingStyle = new Intent(this, ChooseFightingStyle.class);
        startActivity(fightingStyle);
    }  
}
```

However, I'm getting an error message saying "Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(...)'

Can anyone give me some insight on what I'm doing wrong? Or suggestions on how to do this better? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because "this" in your case does not represent a Context, you should try something like this:

```
public void create(Context context){
    Intent fightingStyle = new Intent(context, ChooseFightingStyle.class);
    startActivity(fightingStyle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what would be an example of a context that I would pass into the method?

Comment: well, if you are using the "create" method inside an activity, you can pass "this" (that represents the activity's context) and if you're calling that method in a Fragment you can pass "getContext()" :) there are other cases... but those are the main ones.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#pubctors) class constructors, they can take a string as first argument or a Context. Your Fighter class should be of type Context to pass it as argument. However, if you have a reference to the context, you can pass it too in the Intent constructor.

A suggestion: when you select the Fighter class from the list in the main activity, you can pass the context from the main activity.